# is it possible to query with a logical OR in django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a model 'Organization' which has following fields

```
class Organization(models.Model):
    members = models.ManyToManyField(User,related_name='org_members')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField()
    founder = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='org_founder')
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

To make a query to get all orgs where a user is a member

```
me=User.objects.get(username='damon')
Organization.objects.filter(members=me)
```

Similarly To make a query to get all orgs where a user is a founder

```
Organization.objects.filter(founder=me)
```

I want to write a query which will fetch me all orgs in which a user is a member or courses for which he is the founder.

I tried this as below

```
Organization.objects.filter(members=me or founder=me)
```

This causes `Invalid Syntax` error

Can someone tell me how to make this query

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To query with a logical OR, you need to use the Q objects ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects)):

```
from django.db import models
Organization.objects.filter(models.Q(members=me) | models.Q(founder=me))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
from django.db.models import Q
Organization.objects.filter(Q(members='me') | Q(founder='me'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) objects. That will help you with what you are after.